# kamajayi mudra and it's implications on celibacy

Tags: scripture, upanishads, vedanta, yoga

how can I use kamajayi mudra to become a means of aid in my celibacy?can i use it in the course of simple breathing meditation..or do i have to do a separate kind of affirmation meditation?

Comment: not an answer to your question, but controlling rajasic & tamasic intake is one of the best aid for celibacy - avoid meat, alcohol, eggs, onion, garlic and generally eating outside at restaurants. Adi Shankara starts shloka with 'ahara shudhau sattva shudhi' - from clean food, you get clean mind

Comment: It is dangerous to practise mudras, pranayamas, bandhas without the supervision of a realised teacher. Please do not attempt this on your own. Please seek a proper teacher/guru. vijayeebhava.